# how to change the index of the table that was already created using rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I already have this migration file that was created and the migration was run.

```
class CreateStudentContexts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :student_contexts do |t|
      t.string :student_id, index: true, null: false, limit: 40
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps null: false

      t.index [:student_id, :updated_at], unique: true, name: 'student_context_index'
    end
  end
end
```

Now i want to create a new migration file that will update the index, and the index fields should be student_id and created_at.

Answer (score 4):

This question is kinda old, but in case anyone comes across it:

Justin Wood's answer should work, but with one change: replace the column name in the remove_index method with the name of the index:

```
remove_index :student_contexts, name: 'student_context_index'
```

When the index was created, it was given a specific (non-standard) name with the `name` argument, so you also need to use the `name` argument in the `remove_index` statement. Otherwise, Rails expects the index to have a standard name (in this case "index_student_contexts_on_updated_at").

Answer (score 3):

You can create another migration and change the table. Something like

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :student_contexts, :updated_at
    add_index :student_contexts, :created_at
  end
end
```

would do.

Comment: it throws an error that, "`index_name_for_remove': An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: (StandardError)"    Index name 'index_student_contexts_on_updated_at' on table 'student_contexts' does not exist